# dump_destination in symfony/debug-bundle config

Tags: symfony, symfony4, var-dump

In my team we work with SF4 and use .env.dist (and so .env) for developer specific config. When we develop we find **symfony/var-dumper** very useful, however some devs like to dump in browser and some in console using server:dump command which comes with symfony/debug-bundle. It's very annoying to comment out / uncomment `debug.dump_destination` key over and over after pulling from remote or worry about conflicts when current remote HEAD happens to have this file also edited.

I did my best to debug this and the problem lies here:
`Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DependencyInjection\DebugExtension::load()` checks for `0 === strpos($config['dump_destination'], 'tcp://')` and as
environment variables are not resolved until container is built, then having, let's say, `WHATEVER="tcp://%env(VAR_DUMPER_SERVER)%"` in my **.env** file and `debug.dump_destination: '%env(resolve:WHATEVER)%'` leads to false (at the moment of check dump_destination is `env_93f4ff143f62ce8d_resolve_WHATEVER_e29a13ca55ef040f58272adff34dd9a4`) and everything brokes. As side note, when I don't use env variables but just set  `parameters.whatever: "tcp://%env(VAR_DUMPER_SERVER)%"` and then `debug.dump_destination: %whatever%` everything is fine. Of course I could create new parameters.dist.yaml file and parameters.yaml where the latter would be added to .gitignore but I want to keep and have every developer specific info in one file which is .env .

Summarizing, what can I do to have the key **debug.dump_destination** equal `tcp://%env(VAR_DUMPER_SERVER)%` for one developer and `null` or `~` for another ?

## SOLUTION

Following M. Kebza answer this is the solution I came up with:

**.env**

```
DUMP_SERVER=null # or DUMP_SERVER=tcp://%env(VAR_DUMPER_SERVER)%
```

**Kernel.php**

```
$DUMP_SERVER = getenv('DUMP_SERVER');
if (strtolower($DUMP_SERVER) === 'null' || $DUMP_SERVER === '~') {
    $DUMP_SERVER = null;
}
$container->setParameter('DUMP_SERVER', $DUMP_SERVER);
```

**debug.yaml**

```
debug.dump_destination: "%DUMP_SERVER%"
```

`bin/console cache:clear` is required after every DUMP_SERVER variable change in **.env** file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another ideas how to solve this problem:

- Have default value for `debug.dump_destination` and use ENV variable in environment for each developer to set his preferred solution
- In your `Kernel.php` in method `configureContainer` check for existence of local file for example `local.yaml` and this can be used to override specific configurations, this file should be ignored in git.

Comment: **1.** Won't work. When using `%env(WHATEVER)%` it is taken **as it is** before full container compilation. **2.** Checked this, works pretty nice. However, changing this variable in **.env** is not seen and `bin/console cache:clear` is required.