# Trying to deploy our S4 program, we have a fatal error with debug

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

We wrote an application with SF4. It works fine, even on the remote site, in dev mode.

So we try to get prod mode. In .env, we pass the APP_ENV variable to prod, an we have the message :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "debug" (in /home/olymphys/public_html/config/packages/debug.yml). Looked for namespace "debug", found "framework", "sensio_framework_extra", "doctrine_cache", "doctrine", "doctrine_migrations", "security", "swiftmailer", "twig", "monolog", "easy_admin", "vich_uploader", "webpack_encore" in /home/olymphys/public_html/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php:682 Stack trace: #0 /home/olymphys/public_html/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php(652): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader->validate(Array, '/home/olymphys/...') #1 /home/olymphys/public_html/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php(119): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader->loadFile('/home/olymphys/...') #2 /home/olymphys/public_html/vendor/symfony/config/Loader/FileLoader.php(151): Symfony\Component\D in /home/olymphys/public_html/vendor/symfony/config/Loader/FileLoader.php on line 166

We tried to use [dump_destination in symfony/debug-bundle config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51734687/dump-destination-in-symfony-debug-bundle-config)
and nothing different happen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you have on `packages/debug.yml` should not be there for production.

Move it to `packages/dev/debug.yml` so it's only loaded when `APP_ENV` is set to `dev`.